# Horizontal vs Vertical optimal transport of probability distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, marginal-distribution, wasserstein, transportation

Optimal transport has a primal and dual form. My question is: Is the primal formulation of OT intended for **horizontal movement** of probability mass, whereas the dual formulation is more geared towards optimizing **vertical movement** of probability mass?

I ask because of the way these two are presented in the source slides ([Link](https://imaging-in-paris.github.io/seminar/slides/chizat.pdf)):

Below (slide 15), the **primal OT** is shown on the first line $(P)$, while the **dual OT** is shown on the second line $(D)$:
[image]

Afterwards, the **dual form is revisited** (slide 37) in a section discussing **vertical perturbations** of the probability mass movements:
[image]

Besides these vertical perturbations, the OT textbook by Santambrogio (2015) confirms the existence of a difference between horizontal and vertical movement of probability mass:

[image]
Repeating my earlier question, are there situations that make **dual OT** more applicable than the **primal OT**, and vice versa, having to do with the different goals of reconciling horizontal and vertical distances)

Comment: Could you explain what "vertical movement of probability mass" might be and how exactly it differs from "horizontal" movement?  Note that the "vertical perturbations" illustrated in the lower panel cannot correctly be interpreted as "movement:" these truly alter ("perturb") the probability by adding or subtracting various quantities at each location, but there's no reference to (or concept of) something "moving" from one location (that is, x-coordinate) to another.

Comment: I've added a third figure regarding vertical vs horizontal distances taken from a textbook on OT, rather than limiting the discussion to vertical perturbations

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.  I don't view this as a "movement" of probability: it is, as stated, a *perturbation* -- literally, a *change* of probability -- *without* any change of location.  That's why your new figure does not refer to the left plot as "transport."

Comment: could I be missing that a better way to put the intuition behind OT is that horizontal movements of mass in fact *pile up* the target locations, implying the vertical rise in area there. in other words, horizontal movement causes vertical build-up